# Will Armenia and Azerbaijan permit a tourist to enter if they have the other country's stamp in their passport?

Tags: passports, passport-stamps, azerbaijan, caucasus, armenia

I know that there are certain pairs of countries (which do not get along with each other) where a traveller will not be permitted into one country if they have a stamp in their passport from a visit to the other country.

Considering the history of Armenia and Azerbaijan I'm wondering if these two are such a pair of countries? I was in Armenia last year and I'm considering visiting Azerbaijan this year while I'm in Georgia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://puerrtto.livejournal.com/152718.html?page=2&cut_expand=1#cutid1), you should try to avoid visit both countries with the same passport. If you get two passports (Israel and USA, for example), try to get into one country by one of them, and to other with other passport (as author of the blog did).

The main problem is possible visiting of Nagorno-Karabakh Republic. It is a crime in Azerbaijan (illegal border crossing), so **even if you were in the NKR, don't say a word about that**. They can't prove anything without your words. Be careful and good luck.

Comment: Hmm I only have one passport but I was also thinking of entering NKR since I believe it's a good route from Tbilisi to Kuwait...

Comment: Well, as I know, you wouldn't have any stamp there, but be careful during your trip

Comment: @Keyslinger Thank you. Hope I'll improve my English on this site.

Comment: Some countries will allow their citizens to be issued two passports so that they can visit countries which are in a conflict with one another. So your visa and stamps from NKR can be in one and you enter Azerbaijan with the other.

Comment: blog url is broken.

Comment: @Farid Movsumov Yes, the author removed the post. All you can do - google it from it's cache: `site:puerrtto.livejournal.com 152718.html`

Comment: Here's [the whole blog at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130601011435/http://puerrtto.livejournal.com/152718.html?page=2&cut_expand=1).

Comment: Any reasons to downvote?

Answer (score 16):

Here's some first hand experience (I visited the region a few weeks ago). Visiting Armenia is not a problem for Azerbaijan, nor is it the other way around. What *is* a problem, is having a visa for Nagorno-Karabakh (NKR) in your passport when you want to visit Azerbaijan. Indeed, at best, you will not be let in to Azerbaijan.

It is *said* that NKR has no problem issuing the NKR visa on a separate piece of paper, so that you *can* visit Azerbaijan afterwards, but I can not confirm that.

Comment: Yes I've heard exactly the same actually.

Comment: I can confirm both parts of the response. The first part from my own experience, as I visited both countries in March 2012 on the same passport. For the NKR visa given on a piece of paper, a friend of mind visited it and that's what happened. But you better make sure and ask them to give it on a seperate paper before they glue it in! :)

Comment: Yet another confirmation! I am a Turkish student in Dilijan, Armenia and my Austrian colleague who had a **residence card** in Armenia managed to travel to and fro Baku.

Answer (score 6):

Actually visiting Nagorno-Karabakh Republic is a crime in Azerbaijan, but you won't get in any kind of problem in Armenia because of visiting Azerbaijan.

I visited Armenia with a friend who had an Azerbaijani visa in his passport and in Armenia they asked a couple of questions regarding his visit from Azerbaijan in front of us, then they let him go (I'm an Armenian from Iran and my friend is Iranian.)

Comment: Do you have any references for this?