# Is it possible to travel to Israel if it's not recognised by your passport's country?

Tags: visas, passports, israel, countries, passport-stamps

I'm wondering if it's possible for passport holders of countries that do not recognise other countries to travel to that particular country. Israel is not recognised by the Malaysian passport, so would it be possible for a Malaysian (passport holder) to travel to Israel and just not have their passport stamp, or would Israel refuse the bearer entry/visa?

Comment: Rule for entry are set by the destination country, not your country of origin. In other words, it does not matter if your country recognizes Israel, what matters is the way Israel sees your country. In principle, it's possible that Israel does not care at all, bars entry to all citizens from countries that do not recognize it or puts some restrictions for some but not all of these countries. It's also possible to demonstratively not recognize a country and yet accept its passports under certain conditions (it's the case for Northern Cyprus in France and a handful of other countries).

Comment: There is just no general rule (which makes a lot of sense when you think about it because otherwise it would give foreign countries a lot of control over visa policy).

Comment: However, you might obviously face negative consequences when renewing your passport or coming back to the country that issued your passport if there is some sign of your travels in it.

Comment: One other case I know off the top of my head is trying to enter [Azerbaijan with a Nagorno Karabakh stamp in your passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/328). And there's bound to be some others. So I understand the OP's opposition to the edits. But I also agree that there can't really be a universal answer in such cases - each would need to be addressed separately.

Comment: I've asked a new question about this: **[Besides Arab/Muslim countries re Israel, are there other countries which don't recognize passports of any other countries?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22190)**

Comment: Keep the discussion on topic guys

Answer (score 29):

Israel allows Citizens of all countries to enter its borders, as long as they have an appropriate visa. There are countries for whose citizens Israel doesn't require a visa for a tourist stay of no more than 90 days. Malaysia and the other countries that don't recognize Israel and don't have diplomatic relations with Israel are not on that list so a Malaysian citizen would need to acquire a visa prior to their visit to Israel.

There is no Israeli representation in Malaysia, so a visa request would need to be filed at a representative at another country. Israel does have an [embassy in Singapore](http://embassies.gov.il/singapore/ConsularServices/Pages/online-services-and-forms.aspx). Or one might search the [Israeli Foreign Affair Ministry site](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/Pages/ContactUs.aspx) for more information.

Also it should be noted that while Israel may allow you to enter its borders, [Malaysia has restrictions on visiting Israel](http://ttgasia.com/article.php?article_id=20323). As noted in [answers to other questions on this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/travel-implications-when-going-to-muslim-countries-after-a-visit-to-israel/19481#19481), Israel allows for border control to not stamp a visitor's passport if they ask. This permits the the passport to have no record of the visit to Israel.

Comment: iow, if you visit Israel with your Malaysian passport you may find it hard to go back home without being arrested and thrown in prison.

Comment: @jwenting, not necessarily, as the article indicate, Malaysia does allow some quota of visitors to Israel.

Comment: hence "may". You'd need permission from Malaysia rather than Israel to return home to Malaysia without facing arrest.

Comment: It's also worth noting that as of January 2013, Israel no longer stamps passports on entry. When you enter, you get an 'entry card'. Before 2013, this used to be provided on request. However, now it's mandatory. In other words, visiting Israel no longer leaves a stamp on your passport. ([Source](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/israel/entry-requirements))

Comment: @Adnan, from personal experience, Israel stamps (at least Israeli) passports upon entry and departure after Jan. 2013. In addition they give you an entry card that is proof that you went through passport control and is then taken and ripped by the border control officer standing at the "Entry Gates".

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Well, I guess that `gov.uk` is wrong, then.

Comment: @Adnan, my experience is of an Israeli citizen, it maybe different for foreign citizens.

Answer (score 0):

Every country has the sovereign right to determine who it will or will not allow into its territory. This is irrespective of the views of the country which issued the traveler's identity documents, or any markings thereon.

Therefore, the statement "Israel is not recognised by the Malaysian passport" is essentially meaningless. It is entirely up to the Israeli authorities to decide who they will allow into their territory on whatever basis they choose.

For specific information regarding visa and other entry requirements, I suggest contacting the nearest Israeli embassy. The following Israeli government website also contains visa information:

http://www.goisrael.com/Tourism_Eng/Tourist%20Information/Planning%20your%20trip/Pages/Israel%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.aspx#Visa

Answer (score 0):

I have a Malaysian friend who did it. So yes it is possible. And he did not have any issues with the Malaysian authorities afterwards. I guess they couldn't know about his holiday trip.
He took a flight to Jordan (a neighbor country) and from there drove to Israel with a car he rented. He even went to Gaza.
I think he did that for the thrill, because he was excited to do something forbidden.